# Issues with protractor test when finding element array using repeatable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I've created a protractor test for the following html:

```
<div class="well well-sm" data-ng-repeat="feedback in f.feedbackList">
   Rating:&nbsp;{{feedback.rating}}
   <blockquote class="small">{{feedback.comment}}</blockquote>
</div>
```

In the page.js file I have:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = (function () {
  function AdminFeedbackPage() {
    this.comments = element.all(by.repeater('feedback in f.feedbackList').column('feedback.comment')).map(function (comments) {
        return comments.getText();
    });

    this.ratings = element.all(by.repeater('feedback in f.feedbackList').column('feedback.rating')).map(function (ratings) {
        return ratings.getText();
    });
}

return AdminFeedbackPage; })();
```

and then in the test in my step.js file:

```
var feedbackFound = false;
        var feedbackIndex;

        adminFeedbackPage.comments.then(function (commments) {
            for (var i = 0; i < commments.length; i++) {

                console.log("Comments " + i + ": " + commments[i]);

                if (commments[i] == "TestApplicationFeedback") {
                    feedbackIndex = i;
                    console.log("FEEDBACK INDEX - " + feedbackIndex)
                    feedbackFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }).then(function () {
            expect(feedbackFound).to.be.true;
        }).then(function() {
          adminFeedbackPage.ratings.then(function (ratings) {
              console.log(ratings);
              console.log("RATINGS length " + ratings.length + " and rating is " + ratings[feedbackIndex]);
              expect(ratings[feedbackIndex]).to.equal(3);
          })
        });
```

And I get the following logs:

Comments 0: Decent App

Comments 1: Really like it

Comments 2: TestApplicationFeedback

FEEDBACK INDEX - 2

[]

RATINGS length 0 and rating is undefined

AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 3

This is really confusing my since the comments are being found without any issue, but the ratings are just an empty array and as far as I can tell I have done the same thing for both.

Does anybody have any suggestions/reasons why the ratings aren't being found? I suspect it's something to do with what is in the page.js file, but I have no idea what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks correct... Maybe try `.evaluate()` ([docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate)) instead of `.column()` for that, since it's within the ng-repeat and not on a child element like `feedback.comments`?

Comment: Whereabouts? I tried instead of getText, but I'm guessing you mean instead of .column or possibly in place of the map function somehow?

Comment: Yea I was suggesting in place of `.column`, might even remove the need for map too.  Try this:  `element.all(by.repeater('feedback in f.feedbackList')).evaluate('feedback.ratings').then(function(val) {  console.log(val) })`.  I tried on our app with a different repeater, and it returned an array of values like I was expecting

Comment: Instead of an empty array that gave an array of length 3, but all the values were null.

Comment: Actually, I just needed to change to feedback.rating instead of feedback.ratings and that's worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh awesome, sorry for the typo lol.  I'll type up a quick answer just in case others see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this in the comments above, posting as an answer:

It was just a guess/suggestion based on the HTML, one was a child element and the other was directly inside the repeater (this one was failing to be captured).  So my suggestion was to try using `.evaluate()` [source](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate), which acts as if on scope of the given element.  So replacing `.column()` seems to work:

```
element.all(by.repeater('feedback in f.feedbackList')).evaluate('feedback.rating').then(function(val) {
    console.log(val) // should return an array of values (feedback.rating)
})
```